# If there are $8$ red apples and $10$ green apples, how many ways can I choose $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> If there are $8$ red apples and $10$ green apples, how many ways can I choose $4$?

That part is easy: $18!/14!$. After all, $18$ choices first time, $17$ the second, etc. BUT! What if

> the second time I could only use a red apple, and the third time, I could only choose a green.

I know the answer is less than $18!/14!$, but I would expect $18×8×10×15$.  But I'm wrong.

Comment: Mhh, I would say that you can choose $4$ apples (red or green) in $\sum\limits_{x=0}^4 {8 \choose x} \cdot {10 \choose {4-x}}$ ways.

Comment: Is the selection ordered?

Comment: And are the apples that have the same color considered indistinguishable?

Comment: Hint: start with the second and third apples, and then choose the first and the last.

Comment: No, the red is different from green

Comment: You did not answer any question from the comments. And if you do not choose whom you address nobody will know that you added a comment.

Comment: If you are distinguishing all the apples (which seems the case if you are getting large numbers; otherwise knowing the number of green apples chosen suffices, which is just an integer between $0$ and $4$, for five ways), then the colour of the apples is just a red (or green) herring: the answer will be the number $\binom{8+10}4=3060$ of ways to choose $4$ items among $18$.

Comment: @arthur, color doesn't matter for first choice and the fourth choice.  The second choice has to be a red apple and third choice has to be a green one.  The third choice can be ANY green apple, but I can only choose from the subset of green apples.  And no repeating

Comment: This is not an answer to the question if the apples of the same color are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking for the number of *ordered lists* of $4$ distinct apples, chosen from a set of $18$ (distinguishable) candidates, for which the second on the list is a red apple and the third on the list is a green one.

My approach would be that, since only the total list produced matters, on could get the result by first choosing the second on the list (one out of $8$ candidates), then the third on the list (one out of $10$), and finally the fourth and the first on the list, arbitrary choices among the remaining $16$ respectively $15$ apples. All in all, $8\times 10\times16\times15$ giving $19200$ distinct lists.